# Can I move HTML DOM object to a browser dialog to implement "detach" functionality

Tags: jquery, html, dom, dialog, popup

If I open a browser dialog with `window.open`, can I move HTML DOM object back and forth?

I know how to use jQuery's `.detach()` to move stuff (with all bound events) within the page. I wonder if there is a way to do it between a page and it's child dialog.

The main purpose is to support a "detach" or "tear off" functionality for a widget on a page, into a separate dialog/window.

Comment: Interested in answers; I personally would not bet on that working, if for no other reason than IE's extreme nervousness about inter-window object migration. I'd extract with `.html()` and stuff that in the new page, and then reestablish handlers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to be able to move a DOM Node from one `ownerDocument` to another. DOM Level 1 Core says you will get a `DOMException` with code `WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR`. The proper thing to do is to call `document.importNode` to get a new copy of the content. (There is also `document.adoptNode` to do it without the copying, but it's newer, arriving in DOM Level 3 Core.

However:

1. in the specific case of non-XML HTML documents, many browsers will let you get away with using nodes from one document in another `ownerDocument`.
2. IE doesn't support `importNode`. (Or `adoptNode`, obviously.) You can either fallback to inserting the nodes directly when `importNode` is unavailable, or make a copy of the content in the new document manually, either by DOM-walking or HTML serialisation/parsing. (Both of those will lose information; don't expect to recover arbitrary properties or EventListeners/IE-attached-events.)
3. There can be some issues with having the event path in one document go into code from another document, in IE6-7. When the documents are closed/navigated-away you can get some unexpected behaviours.

In any case, jQuery is not built for this. It encapsulates a reference to the owner document in itself, so when you call `$` from code that originated in document A, you'll be using the `document` object for document A, even if your nodes and event path are now in document B. This will cause a great deal of confusion. With jQuery it is best to keep one copy of the library for each document, and use only that copy to interact with that document.